Compute specs required to build the tensorflow serving docker image
I'm trying to build the Tensorflow Serving docker image from scratch. Currently, I'm burning every CPU I can attempt to spin up. There is no official documentation regarding this.
Does anyone have any guidance on the levels of compute that are required to build this?
